# Stop Form From Submitting Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of select boxes all with a class value = "topic". I want to submit the form only if one or more boxes have a selected value. My code detects if any of the select boxes have a selected value or not but the form submits either way. Just wondering how to stop the form from submitting?

```
<select name="Topic_ACH" id="ddlTopic_ACH" class="topic">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select> 

<select name="Topic_Bankruptcy" id="ddlTopic_Bankruptcy" class="topic">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>

etc.

//At least one Topic checkbox must be checked to submit the form             
 $('#MainContent_btnUpdateSample').click(function (e) {
 var anySelected = false;
 $(".topic option:selected").each(function () {
     if (!$(this).val() == "") {
         anySelected = true;
     }
 });
 if (!anySelected) {
     alert("You must select at least one topic");
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;                    
 }
 });
```

Comment: You must listen to the submit event of the form (you are listening to the click event of a button) in order for e.preventDefault() to work. It prevents the default action on submit (reloading the page), that's not the default action of a click. So change your event listener to listen to the submit event on the form ,NOT the button

Comment: `$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(){return false})`

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use the `submit` event on the form element instead of the `click` event on the form button. Try out the following:

```js
document.querySelector('form#some-form').addEventListener('submit',  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

In combination, you might find merit in the `required` attribute for your `<select>` elements since that simplifies your logic greatly (adding this element requires the user to select a value; if nothing is selected the browser will automatically display any error messages).

(Also you don't need jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this,

```
<input type='submit' id='MainContent_btnUpdateSample' onclick='return handleSelect()' />


function handleSelect() {
 var anySelected = false;
 $(".topic option:selected").each(function () {
     if (!$(this).val() == "") {
         anySelected = true;
     }
  }

 if (!anySelected) {
     alert("You must select at least one topic");
 }

 return anySelected;
}
```